# Sentence Fragment

Tags: sentence-fragments

I have been told that the sentence: "Another element is Mrs. Hale’s act of pulling the stitches from Mrs. Wright’s quilt." is a fragment. I thought "Another element" is the subject of the sentence since "another" is a pronoun and "element" a noun. The "is" in the sentence is an auxiliary verb and ending a sentence with a prepositional phrase ("of pulling the stitches from Mrs. Wright's quilt") is not an error. What am I not seeing?
Thanks so much!

Comment: You are right; it's not a fragment. "Another element" is subject and "is Mrs. Hale’s act of pulling the stitches from Mrs. Wright’s quilt" is predicate,in which "is" is the verb, and the noun phrase "Mrs. Hale’s act of pulling the stitches from Mrs. Wright’s quilt" is predicative complement of "is"..

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence *is* a sentence, not a fragment (assuming that 'fragment' means incomplete sentence). I'd call 'is' a main verb rather than an auxiliary verb, so the sentence is of the form *A is B*. The sentence would still be alright grammatically, though more puzzling to the reader, if it ended on the word 'act'.